# To openParentApplication not responding handleWatchKitExtensionRequest in Watchkit Extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-watch

I am trying to implement apple watch extension. I need to call my iPhone application class methods to trigger the web request. I saw this method in apple documentation i am trying the same.But this method is not calling

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void(^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo))reply
```

any help on this is appreciated.
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html

Here is my code snippet:

```
#import "InterfaceController.h"

- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];

    // Configure interface objects here.
    NSString *requestString = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"callMyRequest"];
    NSDictionary *applicationData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:@[requestString] forKeys:@[@"theRequestString"]];

    [WKInterfaceController openParentApplication:applicationData reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"\nReply info: %@\nError: %@",replyInfo, error);
    }];
}

#import "Appdelegate.h"
#import "MyController.h"

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void(^) (NSDictionary *replyInfo))reply {
    NSString * request = [userInfo objectForKey:@"requestString"];

    if ([request isEqualToString:@"callMyRequest"]) {
        // Do whatever you want to do when sent the message. For instance...
        MyController*  myController = [[MyController alloc] init];
        [myController callMyRequest];
    }

    reply nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must reply something. `reply(@{});`

Also, the method is being called, I'm just not sure you know how to debug the app. You need to go to Debug>Attach To Process>Your App Name (not watchkit app name). You have to do this quick before the process finishes or else it will not trip your breakpoint.

Comment: If i follow any sample application i am getting data from my iPhone app app delegate class. Even if i put break point also it's not going there. @Schemetrical

Comment: @RajuIstalla I know, thats why you need to attach to process to get the breakpoint to trip. If the application isn't returning anything, then there's a problem with your code on your phone (which it will not tell you unless you attach quick enough)

Answer (score 0):

In your app delegate you are checking for an object using the key `requestString`, when it has been stored in the dictionary using the key `theRequestString`. Additionally, you need to return something other than `nil`.